# Is Dirac delta worth its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

Dirac delta is pretty basic concept and we have [multiple questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dirac%20delta) mentioning it. It also causes many confusion, so it is likely to provoke new questions among those who first encounter it. Maybe we should create a tag for it?

Comment: Delta function is a standard mathematical object and corresponding tag exists on Math.SE (with 500+ questions). But does it have any particular relevance for statistics to warrant a tag here?

Comment: @amoeba it is used in statistics and probability and seems to cause some confusion for those who first encountered it. Moreover, in probability it can be regarded as a degenerate *distribution* and understood as it it provokes on-topic questions.

Comment: The Dirac delta is implicit to many stochastic processes as it is the identity function for convolution. However, it would not be used alone, but always in conjunction with something else. I do not personally see any particular reason for it to appear as a stand alone tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I am providing an answer so to bump the question and close it with some conclusion.*

Personally I'd considered `[dirac-delta]` tag useful. The question already got eight upvotes and one negative (?) comment by *Carl*. I'd say that the response to this idea is positive, so I'd consider creating it.

So to close this issue: is there anyone who does not agree with this idea? Are there any more arguments against it?

**EDIT**

Since there is not much interest in the thread *and* it got rather positive response, I created the [dirac-delta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirac-delta) tag and started re-tagging.

Comment: I don't necessarily have a problem w/ the growth of the number of tags, or having tags that are only applied to a few threads. I think tags should be intrinsically meaningful, have excerpts, & not be duplicates / synonyms. If you think it would be useful, you should make the tag.

Comment: So, we promote the identity function for convolution to tag status, but not the identity http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/what-do-you-think-of-the-new-tag-identity. So, we name individual leaves, and ignore their tree. What, I muse, would we do with a whole forest? LOL.