# What do you think of the new tag: identity

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

I confess that I made a new tag: `identity`. A search of 'identity' on the main site yielded 1110 questions, and being able to label something as an identity and search for it is a good thing. Identities are extremely important when writing new statistical density functions, and can disguise two expressions that are equal, but not recognizably so. When I develop new pdf's, CDF's, expected values, and the like, I keep a separate list of useful identities that makes it possible for me to work through those statistical formulas.

Identities are important to note explicitly because if you do not know them by heart, or at least recognize that they might exist for a function, you will be stuck completely doing integration (e.g., CDF finding), simplification, expectation, proofs, and other mathematical steps. Almost any class of functions has numerous identities the existence of which should be known to do novel statistical development work. For example, hyperbolic functions have [numerous identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Identities).

So, question is, what do you think about `identity` as a new tag? See [Understanding an Estimator Identity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195460/understanding-an-estimator-identity) as an example.

Comment: Personally, I do not see how this tag should be useful or helpful. Do you intend to create [equality], [inequality], [formula], [expression] as well?

Comment: @amoeba Summarizing, you do not find `identity` to be an unusually important concept, nor do you differentiate `identity` from the other search terms you mockingly put forward.  I do not intend to create `equality`, `inequality`, `formula`, or `expression`. The importance of identities has become more apparent to me the more I have explored hitherto uncharacterized distributions and physically relevant novel statistical physics. I would suggest that if you were to do likewise, you would understand better why I hold identities in high esteem.

Comment: Well, I'd say let's wait and see if people are going to support your new tag. Until then I'd suggest you do not do much re-tagging.

Comment: @amoeba Not at all. My thought was "Wow, how many important identities there are in statistics, for example for expected value; we should have a tag for that; it would be very useful." I am not trying to convince you. Each to his own.

Comment: @amoeba Sorry, I put the tag on the main site. My creating it on the Meta site was carelessness on my part.

Comment: @amoeba I took `identity` off the Meta site

Comment: @amoeba Why do you not answer that you do not like the tag, so I can vote it down?

Comment: Like @amoeba, I don't see any value in having an `[identity]` tag. One thing that might help is if you made a tag excerpt for it. It isn't remotely clear to me what the tag is supposed to be for, or how to decide if it picks out anything of value about a question. Is the idea that it should be on any thread that includes an equals sign?

Comment: @gung Hardly. I gave an example in the question. I find it astounding that I am getting so little support on this. This tag already exists on the http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity?sort=newest&days=30, was used 5 times this month on that site and also has no description on that site. Why? It is obvious to a student mathematician (the http://math.stackexchange.com/ site is not http://mathoverflow.net/; the professional site) what it is and why it is so important. I can make a tag description here, only if our site expresses a student's level appreciation of the identity.

Comment: @gung I put in more information about identities in my question. Seriously, if all one does with statistics is learn what others have done, then 90% of the fun goes la-la. The real fun is making up completely new stuff, and for that you need identities.

Comment: Re Math.SE: the [identity] tag there was used 5 times *ever*; it seems it's a stray tag that was only created this month, perhaps accidentally. It lacks a tag description *not* because its meaning is obvious for users of that site but because it's a tag that nobody cares about (and nobody cared to create until this month).

Comment: @amoeba Well, it was not I who created it. And if it were a "stray" tag, which I take to be mean something like "lost doggie," it would not be finding usage at all. Seriously, do you so little development work that you do not need to find identities as one of your most helpful activities? I would think that someone of your high reputation would be automatically supportive of this. I am disappointed, a bit, nothing I will lose sleep over, but still.

Comment: The problem with this tag is simply that its scope is unclear, as @gung wrote. For example, we don't have a [theorem] tag; nobody will say that theorems are not helpful -- of course they are. But a [theorem] tag would be too unspecific, would have an unclear scope, and so it does not exist. I think the same can be said about [identity].

Comment: @amoeba I agree with you, I wouldn't suggest a `theorem` tag either, just an `identity` tag. Theorems are not something I would search for, but equivalent things I would note. My reason for this is that proofs are intuitive, if you know the rather non-intuitive identities you will need to make them, and if you do not, then you will be stuck like a plum in pudding. Identities are an organizational heading for functions on Wikipedia, Mathematica and most sites where math is to be used creatively. They are listed because the odds of coming up with one by accident or intent is small.

Comment: As a general rule, *every* tag should have an excerpt, no matter how obvious it seems to you. If you create a tag, you should add an excerpt. Consider that novice users will possibly end up adding `[identity]` on questions like 'how to add an ID variable to my panel data since it's in long format', or some such.

Comment: @gung OK, I have made one. It is now "under review," since, for whatever reason, I do not have the authority to do that without review. If you have any other suggestions or comments, please do not hesitate to communicate them. I am keeping in mind that we are all trying to make thing better.

Comment: Thanks, that's a real improvement. No one can edit tag wikis w/o going through the review until their rep is >20k, or they are elected as a moderator.

Comment: The excerpt is helpful, so I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: "An identity is a generally non-intuitive equivalence between two mathematical expressions." This excerpt definitely helps a lot.

Comment: But I am still not 100% convinced...I somehow agree with @amoeba, that the concrete, complete scope of this tag would seem unclear to me.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple good reasons mentioned in the comments, but let me add my five cents, especially as you [pinged me](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/is-dirac-delta-worth-its-own-tag/4417?noredirect=1#comment11493_4417) on my own question

> So, we promote the identity function for convolution to tag status,
>   but not the identity meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/….
>   So, we name individual leaves, and ignore their tree. What, I muse,
>   would we do with a whole forest? LOL.

I guess that you mention *the* reason why your proposal was downvoted. Such tag would be *too broad* to be helpful. Using your own example, `[forest]` tag is not helpful if you are looking precisely for `[blueberries]`, or `[mushrooms]`, and if you are looking for mushrooms in the forest, then since they are a subset of items in the forest, it is enough to search for them directly. I guess that if you are looking for information involving identity, then you are not interested in going through all the possible identities in probability theory, but an identity that is connected to some specific problem of your interest.

Moreover if we had `[identity]` tag, then maybe we also should create other tags as: `[equality]`, `[ineqality]`, `[integral]`, `[axiom]` etc. What if you asked a question that involved using some axioms, identities, inequalities and calculating integrals? Would using all those tags be *really* needed in here? How would you decide which of those tags are more important then others?

You could check also [Tag-candidates for removal](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/tag-candidates-for-removal#) thread or go through [other discussions about tags](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) to see why we deleted or considered deleting other tags. In general, *too specific*, or *too broad* tags are often considered not very useful.

Comment: What I was getting at is the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) of an algebra. Most people have not studied abstract algebra so would not know that the basis of any algebra is the identity function, and thus how that function is fundamental to any other manipulation made within that algebraic construct. That our readers are unimpressed with how pivotal the identity concept is, is underwhelming.